# JavaFX - Help regarding Text/Label

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm a newbie in JavaFX. So i was wondering about this small topic

Label label= new Label("Emergency");
     System.out.println(label);

Output:

```
 Label@17bcb625[styleClass=label]'Emergency'
```

I need to print only 'Emergency'. How do i get rid of 'Label@17bcb625[styleClass=label]'

Now i got the answer too.
 String text = label.getText();

I got banned of asking further questions because of downvotes. Help me through this -> ban

Comment: You should read the docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html

Comment: As @MichaelPickett already mentioned - you should start with the basics of JavaFX programming. Anybody had to start so it's really nothing you have to feel uncomfortable with. A really good beginners tutorial is that from **code.make** being available at (http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
String labelText =  label.getText ();
```

`System.out.println(labelText);`